# Cordova (Phonegap) ChildBrowser crashes when closing in landscape

Tags: cordova, childbrowser

I use Cordova 1.9.0 and the latest iOS ChildBrowser plugin. In the `ChildBrowserViewController.m` file I have set row 157 to return YES to be able to autorotate the ChildBrowser, and this works well -- as it should. Having the app itself only working in portrait mode.

If I open the ChildBrowser and rotate to landscape and then try to close it with the DONE button, this makes the ChildBrowser stop working and freezes and after a little while it crashes the app. And this is when I have opened the ChildBrowser in an Ajax loaded subpage!

But if I open the ChildBrowser in my index file then it closes as it should. I don't understand why it is working in the index file and not in the subpage. This worked exactly as it should in the ChildBrowser when I used Phonegap.0.9.6 prior to Cordova.

Any input really, really appreciated, thanks!